# Передача данных между JPanel

Tags: java

Суть проблемы. Например, есть четыре файла:

```
 JForm.java;
 jPanel1.java;
 jPanel2.java;
 jPanel3.java;
```

---

В `JPanel1` я перетаскиваю два оставшиеся `jPanel2` и `jPanel3` в `jTabbedPane`. В JForm я перетаскиваю JPanel1.

В  файле `JPanel2` и  `JPanel3`  есть по два компонента:

1. JLabel.
2. JButton.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне с кнопки (`JButton`) из `JPanel3` поменять текст в `Jlabel` из `JPanel2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратившись по ссылке к объекту класса JPanel2, у вас в любом случае должна где-то храниться ссылка по КРАЙНЕЙ МЕРЕ на объект JPanel2. И она в каком-то виде должна быть доступна в классе JPanel3.

Вашу архитектуру я не знаю, слово "перетаскиваю" мне ничего не говорит, скорее всего, у вас что-то подобное:

```
public class JForm extend JFrame {

    private jPanel1 jpanel1;
    private jPanel2 jpanel2;
    private jPanel3 jpanel3;

    //Если этого метода нет, сделайте его   
    public JPanel2 getJPanel2(){
        return jPanel2;
    }
}
```

Сделайте в классе JPanel3 ссылку на Jpanel2 (или лучше всего на JForm, но это все зависит от вашей архитектуры):

```
public JPanel3 extend JPanel {
    private JForm owner;

    public setOwner(JForm owner){
        this.owner = owner
    }

}
```

И после того как был создан объект JPanel3, передайте ему ссылку:

```
jpanel3.setOwner(this);
```

и тогда в обработчике события вызывайте:

```
owner.getJpanel2.getJLabel.setText("This is new Text!");
```

Comment: Все сделал как вы и сказали, появилась ошибка 
>Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Залейте куда-нибудь ваш код. Вы обращаетесь к объявленному, но не инициализированному конструктором объекту. Посмотрите, где вы создаете объект, а где обращаетесь к нему. Создавать нужно всегда раньше. 

А еще лучше создайте несколько классов типа ClassA, ClassB, ClassC с какими-нибудь полями и методами, пусть объект класса A будет полем класса B, а объект класса С будет полем класса A. Потренируйтесь с созданием и инициализацией классов, с областями видимости. Вы потратите время, но получите базовое понимание ООП и у вас не будет вопросов, аналогичных вашему.

Comment: Я залил код на яндекс диск https://yadi.sk/d/XCmtD5ecdsCk5

Comment: Вы создаете объект с перегруженным конструктором, не присваивая созданный объект ничему до метода initComponents, а потом пересоздаете объект. 

Если вы хотите передавать ссылку на frame в конструкторе, то 1) передавайте его в методе InitComponents класса NewJFrame 2) В конструкторе класса NewJPanel1 после передачи NewJFrame вызовите собственный InitComponents, как в конструкторе по умолчанию. Только судя по всему генератор кода NetBeans это вам просто сделать не даст - вывод: сделайте в точности, как я посоветовал в основном ответе и вызывайте:initComponents();newJPanel11.setOwner(this);

Comment: Серьезно, почитайте книги, потренируйтесь на тестовых классах, чтобы ПОНИМАТЬ, что вы делаете.

Comment: Спасибо большое все сделал, все заработало!!!